# How can I validate scanf numeric input

Tags: c, validation, input, scanf

I have a simple question. I'm learning linked lists and my data type is `int`. I'm wondering how can validate it where it doesn't allow to take in alphabetic input.

When I do it the way I have it, it doesn't print the message. So how can I properly do something like that?

My code:

```c
node * createLinkedList()
{
    node * head = NULL;
    node * temp = NULL;
    node * p = NULL;
    
    while ((scanf("%d", &(temp->data))) !=EOF )
    {
        if ((temp->data>= 'a' && temp->data<= 'z') || (temp->data>= 'A' && temp->data<= 'Z')){
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR alph is not allowed");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `fprintf` prints to a file, so you need to tell it which file. Did you perhaps mean `printf`(no leading f ?

Comment: @MSalters it wouldnt matter if changed it to printf it would not even go into the if statement

Comment: Well you access the `data` member of `temp`, which is `NULL`... can you please give a more precise description of what output you actually get (actual behavior) in addition to the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%d` `scanf` specifier is to read `int`, if an alphabetic character is inputed, `scanf` will fail to read it and `temp->data` will retain its previous value.

A better condition for your cycle would be:

```
while (scanf("%d", &(temp->data)) == 0) //while input is not correctly parsed...
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR alph is not allowed\n"); //...print error message...
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} //...and clear stdin
}
```

This makes it so that if the input is not parseable as an `int` a new input will be asked until a good value is inputed.

Note that, as [@JohnBode pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260139/how-can-i-validate-scanf-numeric-input/64260241?noredirect=1#comment113639331_64260241), an input starting with a digit but that contains alphabetic characters will be parsed until the character is found, *i.e.* `123abc4` will parse `123`. If you want to avoid this, using a combination of [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) is a more robust method and will allow you to validate inputs like the above.

If it's something that you want to allow to happen, and continue using `scanf`, don't forget you need to then clear `stdin` which will have the characters that were not parsed, (in the exemplified case `abc4\n`), before asking for new inputs, [@JohnBode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64264714/6865932) covers these matters perfectly, check that out.

---

There is another problem in the code you show, your `temp` pointer is `NULL`, it is not able to store any data. Either declare it as an object or allocate memory for it. As it is, it leads to [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3).

---

Comment: @DavidRanieri, too late, OP added `stderr`.

Comment: fprintf(stderr,"ERROR"); what I meant just forgot to add that

Comment: if ((temp->data) == 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR");
        return 0;
      } and it worked thank you!

Comment: This will not catch bad input like `"12w45"` - it will successfully convert and assign `"12"` but leave `"w45"` in the input stream to foul up the next read.

Comment: @JohnBode, disclaimer added.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to validate integer input, then you can't rely on `%d` alone.  It won't catch and reject bad entries like `"12w45"` - it will successfully convert and assign `"12"` but will leave `"w45"` in the input stream to foul up the next read.

There are two ways around this.  One is to scan and check the character immediately following the input, like so:

```
int tmp;
char dummy = 0;

int r;

if ( (r = scanf( "%d%c", &tmp, &dummy )) == 2 )
{
  // if following character is whitespace, then this is a valid numeric input
  if ( isspace( dummy ) )
    temp->data = tmp;
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "non-numeric character '%c' (%d) detected in input\n",
      isprint( dummy ) ? dummy : '.', dummy );

    fprintf( stderr, "clearing out input stream\n" );
    while ( getchar() != '\n' )
      ; // empty loop
  }
}
else if ( r == 1 ) // only thing following numeric input was EOF
{
  temp->data = tmp;
}
else if ( r == 0 )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Non-numeric input detected, clearing input stream\n" );
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ; // empty loop
}
else
{
  fprintf( stderr, "EOF or error detected on input\n" );
}
```

A better way to do this in my opinion is to avoid using `scanf` entirely - read your input as a string using `fgets`, then use `strtol` or `strtod` to perform the conversion:

```
char buffer[13]; // 11 decimal digits plus sign plus string terminator;
                 // should be able to store the decimal string representation
                 // of any 32-bit integer;

if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) )
{
  // chk will point to the first character *not* converted by strtol
  char *chk;
  int tmp = (int) strtol( buffer, &chk, 10 );
  if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Detected non-numeric character '%c' (%d) in input\n",
      isprint( *chk ) ? *chk : '.', *chk );
  }
  else
  {
    temp->data = tmp;
  }
}
else
{
  fprintf( stderr, "EOF or error on input\n" );
}
```

When you're doing this kind of validation, use a temporary to store the converted value until you've finished; do not update your actual target until you know the value is good.

Comment: Just to be thorough you could add `errno` check  for out of range conversion.

Comment: @anastaciu: true.  May do that later.